# Use explicitely instantiated template functions from another project in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2008

I have two projects ProjA and ProjB in one solution in visual studio 2008. ProjA depends on stuff in ProjB. ProjB contains only headers, so nothing has to be build and no library exists. ProjB defines a template function templB in a header TemplB.h. ProjA uses that template function as templB. Everything works fine so far. However, when I explicitely instantiate templB in TemplB.h I get a linker error LNK2001 telling me that templB is an unresolved external symbol.

Where is the problem? Does VS expect the explicitely instantated template to be in some object file or library in ProjB that I have to link against, even if there aren't any object files in ProjB???

Thanks.

I put two minimal test projects here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16089481/Projects.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use *declaration* instead of *instantiation*...

```
template <int N> int id() {return N;}

template<> int id<2>(); // just declare id<2> specialisation: definition needed.
template int id<3>();   // Explicit instantiation of id<3>.
```